# MongoDB aggregation pipeline not working properly

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'am trying to make an exercise with MongoDB database where I need to find movies in a movies collection , where the same person appears in cast, directors, and writers.

[image]

I tried this code :

```
//first match the writers, directors and cast arrays which are not empty.

db.movies.aggregate( [  {$match : {$and : [ {writers: {$elemMatch: {$exists: true}}} , {directors: {$elemMatch: {$exists: true}}} , {cast: {$elemMatch : {$exists: true}}} ]}}
```

```
//then make an intersection between the matched results
,   {$project: {"labers of love" :{$setIntersection: ["$writers", "$cast", "$directors"]}, _id: 0 } } ] ).pretty()
```

However , when I run this command I still get empty arrays which should not be the case. I'am not sure if this pipeline is working properly. When I run only the $match command I dont seem to get any empty array.

Comment: show some example documents or schema structure.

Comment: Hi mate , does this picture help ?

Comment: okay just remove `$elemMatch` operator its not needed. for example check write fields exists  `{ writers: { $exists: true } }`